# NestJS/TypeORM error: The value passed as UUID is not a string when inserting record

Tags: postgresql, graphql, nestjs, typeorm

I created a NestJS sample application that uses TypeORM to access the Postgres database.

[The complete codes can be found from this link](https://github.com/hantsy/nestjs-graphql-sample).

There are two entities like this.

```js
@Entity({ name: 'posts' })
export class PostEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id?: string;

  @Column()
  title: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  content?: string;

  @OneToMany((type) => CommentEntity, (comment) => comment.post, {
    cascade: true,
  })
  comments?: Promise<CommentEntity[]>;

  @ManyToOne((type) => UserEntity, { nullable: true })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'author_id' })
  author?: UserEntity;

  @RelationId((post: PostEntity) => post.author)
  authorId?: string;

  @CreateDateColumn({ name: 'created_at', type: 'timestamp', nullable: true })
  createdAt?: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn({ name: 'updated_at', type: 'timestamp', nullable: true })
  updatedAt?: Date;
}

@Entity({ name: 'comments' })
export class CommentEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column()
  content: string;

  @ManyToOne((type) => PostEntity, (p) => p.comments)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'post_id' })
  post: PostEntity;

  @RelationId((comment: CommentEntity) => comment.post)
  postId?: string;

  @CreateDateColumn({ name: 'created_at', type: 'timestamp' })
  createdAt: Date;
}
```

When adding a comment through the GraphQL endpoint, which will call [the following codes](https://github.com/hantsy/nestjs-graphql-sample/blob/master/api/src/gql/service/posts.service.ts#L67-L79).

```
  addComment(id: string, comment: string): Observable<Comment> {
    const entity = new CommentEntity();
    Object.assign(entity, {
      content: comment,
      postId: id,
    });
    return from(this.commentRepository.save(entity)).pipe(
      map((c) => {
        return { id: c.id, content: c.content } as Comment;
      }),
    );
  }
```

When [running the e2e tests](https://github.com/hantsy/nestjs-graphql-sample/blob/master/api/test/app.e2e-spec.ts#L124-L141) it will fail due to an error message(I added a `console.log` to print the GraphQL errors in the response body):

```sh
addComment errors: [{"message":"The value passed as UUID is not a string"}]
```

Comment: Did you manage to fix this issue ?